# Simple Excel Issue with IFERROR

Tags: excel, formula

I have a list of values like:

```
0.327
0.325
0.327
0.35
0.3585
#N/A
#N/A
0.361
0.377
0.364
0.373
0.393
#N/A
#N/A
0.398
0.405
0.42
```

I want to replace all the #N/As with the value in the row above them (so the first two N/As would both become 0.3585, for example). I tried using IFERROR but am not sure how to word the syntax so that it takes on the value of the above row.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data start in cell `A1`, then enter this formula in cell `B2`:

```
=IFERROR(A2,B1)
```

Now, drag it down as far as you need.

Comment: I was about to say the same!  OP, you'll need to put that in a second column, because if you try to put it in the first column, you'll see the logic doesn't work. `=IfError(A2,A1)` wouldn't work in A2, because it's a circular formula.  It looks in A2 (which is your formula, not a value) ...therefore, put the formula in Col. B.